# UnicodeDecodeError issue when downloading image and uploading

Tags: python, python-3.x

When trying to upload a downloaded file to s3 I'm getting this error:

```
# *** UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

My understanding is my file is in bytes, I'm not sure what the final open is doing.  How can I get this working please?

```
def download(url, file_name):
    with open(file_name, "wb") as file:
        response = requests.get(url)
        file.write(response.content)

def upload(cropped_img):
    s3_connection = boto.connect_s3()
    bucket = s3_connection.get_bucket(settings.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME)
    key = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket, 'th/' + cropped_img)
    with open(cropped_img) as f:
        key.send_file(f)
```

Comment: error at line number ?

Comment: Full working code and full stacktrace please

Comment: Wild guess: `open(cropped_img)` must be changed to `open(cropped_img, 'rb')` in order to open the file in binary mode (by default in Python3 it is text mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must open the file in binary mode:

```
with open(cropped_img, 'rb') as f:
    key.send_file(f)
```

Alternatively you can use the [`boto.s3.key.Key.set_contents_from_filename()`](https://boto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.set_contents_from_filename) method:

```
key.set_contents_from_filename(cropped_img)
```

Comment: Open still wasn't working even in rb (bad request) but set_content_from_filename is.  Thanks,